# receive timeout in docker slim while reducing docker image size

Tags: docker, docker-image

I tired to reduce my docker image size using docker slim but facing connection time out issue
i have used this command: ./docker-slim build --http-probe

but got the below error

INFO[0008] docker-slim: http probe - GET http://127.0.0.1:32792/ error: Get http://127.0.0.1:32792/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:32792: getsockopt: connection refused

INFO[0008] docker-slim: HTTP probe done.

INFO[0270] sendCmd(): receive timeout...

Can anyone help on this ??

Answer (score 0):

The command appears to be incomplete. The target image name/ID is missing. If there was a target take a look at the (stopped) container docker-slim created analyzing your image. Use the standard 'docker ps -a' and 'docker logs' commands for that.